# SQL set division

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently studying for a final, and one of the study questions from a previous exam is as follows:

You have the following schema:
**Student**( `Snum`: integer, `Sname`: string, `Major`: string, `Class`: string, `Age`: string)
**Course**( `Cname`: string, `Meets_at`: time, `Room`: string, `Fid`: Integer)
**Faculty**( `Fid`: Integer, `Fname`: string, `Deptid`: integer)
**Enrolled**( `Snum`: integer, `Cname`: integer)

The question I am having problems with is:

> "Find the names of all faculty members who teach in every room that
>   some class meets"

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( Fname )
FROM (FACULTY NATURAL JOIN COURSE AS C1), COURSE AS C2
WHERE C1.Room = C2.Room
GROUP BY Fname,C2.Cname
WHERE COUNT(C1.Room) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Room)) 
                        FROM COURSE
                        WHERE Cname = C2.Cname);
```

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm not sure if this is right.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe that "*where some class meets*" implies that there should be at least one student enrolled in such class, so you would need to use `Enrolled` table as well.

Comment: I am not sure if that is necessary; there are a total of 6 questions on this schema, and not all of the other questions use all of the tables.

Comment: You may be right at that.

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  _"...who teach in every room..."_ - Does that mean only faculty members who teach in at least once in each and every room in which a class meets?  If a course is defined but has no students, does that count? Or, is it all faculty members who teach in at least one room in which a class meets?  Maybe this is a test to see if you can cope with the horrible phrasing of requirements in the real business world :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes I think you are on the right track with the strategy of matching the count per faculty member to the count of distinct rooms on the course table.

try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.Fname
FROM 
Faculty AS F
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Fid, COUNT(DISTINCT Room) AS cnt FROM Course
    GROUP BY Fid
    ) rooms_per_faculty 
    ON F.Fid = rooms_per_faculty.Fid
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Room) AS cnt FROM Course) rooms_that_meet 
    ON rooms_per_faculty.cnt = rooms_that_meet.cnt
```

(might help to have a little data to play around with.  in the below example, only Dr.4 meets the criteria - teaching in all three course rooms - A,B,C)

```
create local temporary table course(Room varchar(1), Fid int);
create local temporary table faculty(Fid int, Fname varchar(3));
insert into faculty
    select 1, 'DR1'
union select 2, 'DR2'
union select 3, 'DR3'
union select 4, 'DR4';

insert into course
    select 'A',1
union select 'B',1
union select 'A',2
union select 'C',3
union select 'B',4
union select 'A',4
union select 'C',4;
```